# how to deploy SSIS package to sql server instance

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

i have created one SSIS package for importing data from `Excel` to `Sql DB`.
i also deployed it on `SQL SERVER Instance`,but when i am runing that package throw job its gives some error.

```
ERROR:  "Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010.
 All rights reserved.    Started:  11:03:12  Error: 2013-03-19 11:03:12.84     Code: 0xC0202009    
 Source: Package2 Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  
Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''. 
 It is already opened exclusively by another user<c/> or you need permission to view its data.". 
 End Error  Error: 2013-03-19 11:03:12.84     Code: 0xC020801C     
Source: Creating Staging for Data Excel Data Source [1]    
 Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. 
 The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.
  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. 
 End Error  Error: 2013-03-19 11:03:12.84     Code: 0xC0047017     
Source: Creating Staging for Data SSIS.Pipeline     
Description: component "Excel Data Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. 
 End Error  Error: 2013-03-19 11:03:12.84     Code: 0xC004700C    
 Source: Creating Staging for Data SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  
End Error  Error: 2013-03-19 11:03:12.84     Code: 0xC0024107  
   Source: Creating Staging for Data      Description: There were errors during task validation. 
 End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
 Started:  11:03:12  Finished: 11:03:12  Elapsed:  0.219 seconds. 
 The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
```

I am using `32 bit OS`,`.XLS` Excel file for import,which is `MS EXCEL 2003`.

I need solution cananybody help me....???

Comment: The error states that the `excel file` is open .Try to close all  instances of excel file and re run the package

Comment: Thanks Praveen its working fine.m doing silly mistack

Comment: Please post your Answer and hence marked the Question as Answered, so that other can get help from the Question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your package is failing is because you have the excel file open. Close the file and try running the package again.

Error Message:  "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''. 
 It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view its data.".